# Date format always return nil when using 12hr date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm trying to convert a string to a date, using the following code:

```
let dateFormmater = DateFormatter();  
dateFormmater.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC");  
dateFormmater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z";  
let date = dateFormmater.date(from: "2018-06-13T15:33:47.796Z");
```

When the iPhone is set to 24hr mode, this works perfectly, and a new date object is created, but when the iPhone is set to 12hr mode, the date formatter returns nil.
Also, trying to get a string from date using the same date format while the iPhone is set to 24hr mode, results in a normal date, but using this in 12hr mode, results in the hours being presented both in 12hr and 24hr format,
e.g: 2018-07-05T208:17:22.019 PMZ.
note that the hour is 208 PM...

Has anyone encountered this before, and has a solution for this?

Cheers,

P.s this problem replicate able 1:1 in objective-c, using the corresponding classes.

Comment: btw , use `dateFormatter` instead of `dateFormmater` :)